# Multiple Linear Regression in C#

Tags: c#, linear-regression, math.net, mathnet-numerics

I want to make a multiple linear regression in C#. I am trying to achieve this with MathNet.Numerics, but I keep getting the error "Matrix dimensions must agree 2x3".

```
/*****************************************************
    * MathNet.Numerics Multiple linear regression test *
    ****************************************************/

var ydata = new double[] { 15, 20, 25, 55, 95 };
var xdata = new[] { new[] { 1.0, 4.0 }, new[] { 2.0, 5.0 }, new[] { 3.0, 6.0 } };

var x = DenseMatrix.OfColumns(2, 3, xdata);
var y = new DenseVector(ydata);

var p = x.QR().Solve(y); // error: matrix dimensions must agree 2x3
var a = p[0];
var b = p[1];

MessageBox.Show(a.ToString(), "Test");
MessageBox.Show(b.ToString(), "Test");
```

Comment: Hmmm...mismatch of 5 values in ydata with 6 (2x3) values in xdata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception text is really bad in this case, we should fix this.

There are two concrete problems causing this to fail:

- The system with 3 unknowns but only 2 equations/samples (2x3 matrix) is under-defined; Applying a regression to such a problem does not actually make any sense as there is an infinite number of exact solutions.
- For these two samples/equations the right hand side y has actually 5 values (instead of 2, to match each sample)

Maybe it is easier to start with the new `Fit` class available in v3. For example, let's do an ordinary regression with the following samples:

```
a    b         y
1.0, 4.0  -->  15.0
2.0, 5.0  -->  20.0
3.0, 2.0  -->  10.0
```

With the problem to find u, v and w that minimize the error with these samples in

```
y ~= u + a*v + b*w
```

With the Fit class this would look like the following:

```
double[] p = Fit.MultiDim(
    new[] {new[] { 1.0, 4.0 }, new[] { 2.0, 5.0 }, new[] { 3.0, 2.0 }},
    new[] { 15.0, 20, 10 },
    intercept: true);
// p = [u,v,w] = [-1.25,1.25,3.75], hence y ~= -1.25 + 1.25*a + 3.75*b
```

With linear algebra and matrix decompositions the same could look like:

```
var A = DenseMatrix.OfArray(new[,] {
           { 1.0, 1.0, 4.0 },
           { 1.0, 2.0, 5.0 },
           { 1.0, 3.0, 2.0 }});
var b = new DenseVector(new[] { 15.0, 20, 10 });
var p2 = A.Solve(b);
// p = [-1.25,1.25,3.75]
```

Does that help?

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. There's a small typo: "A.QR().Solve(b);" right? It worked that way.

Comment: On v2 you need to explicitly choose the QR decomposition, yes. In v3 there is a new Matrix.Solve method that automatically selects one - in this case it would have chosen the faster LU decomposition since the matrix is square.